# Cannot shutdown or restart using Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: shutdown, restart

I use Ubuntu 12.10 recently installed. Now it cannot shutdown or restart. I remember it was shut-downed or restarted properly a few days ago. Now when I shutdown it, the screen turns to black swiftly that I only see a few statements beginning from "stopping ....". Any suggestion?   Mike

Answer (score 1):

Try using the command **reboot** or **shutdown -h now** with root login. Give more detail about what error you get.

Comment: I've used command you suggested and also click the upper-right corner commands. They are all right now. I really don't know why.

Comment: You said "They are all right now". Does it mean your problem is solved?

Comment: Yes, the problem is solved.

Comment: If my suggestion helped you then you should select my answer as the correct one :)

Answer (score -1):

Try updating GRUB (`sudo update-grub2`). This solved the problem for me.